# Carousel no funciona en BS

Tags: html, css, frontend

mi carousel no estaria funcionando, linkie bs a traves de cdn en mi head del html. copio y pego el codigo de bs5 tal cual como está. El carousel consiste de 6 imagenes con sus captions respectivos pero al momento de querer cambiar de imagen, no hace nada.
El diseño del carousel está bien, aparece centrado y prolijo , pero el problema es que no estaría funcionando.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target=".carousel-item 0" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target=".carousel-item 1" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target=".carousel-item 2" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target=".carousel-item 3" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target=".carousel-item 4" data-bs-slide-to="4" aria-label="Slide 5"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target=".carousel-item 5" data-bs-slide-to="5" aria-label="Slide 6"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="../assets/images/carouselPizzeria1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="chef cocinando">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Frescura y calidad</h5>
            <p>En nuestra cocina solo utilizamos productos con estandar de calidad</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../assets/images/carouselPizzeria2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="foto caja de pizza">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Diseño</h5>
            <p>Mantenemos los mas minimos detalles hasta en nuestro packaging</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../assets/images/carouselPizzeria3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="carteleria neon">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Carteleria</h5>
            <p>¡Agregamos nuestro estilo newyorkino a nuestro salon!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../assets/images/carouselPizzeria4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="terraza">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Nuestra gran terraza</h5>
            <p>La terraza mas bella del Village climatizada, con excelente vista</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../assets/images/carouselPizzeria5.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="cocineros pizzeria">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Maestros en lo que hacemos</h5>
            <p>Nuestra cocina goza del personal mas capacitado del mercado</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../assets/images/carouselPizzeria6.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="cocineros pastas">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Al que le quepa el poncho...</h5>
            <p>
              Cada cocinero que trabaja con nosotros, se dedica solo a su especialidad,
              para poder brindar la mejor calidad posible en lo que elabora.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es que en realidad no solo copiaste y pegaste, modificaste el `data-bs-target` y por eso no funciona

El carrusel tiene un `id` que por ahora es `carouselExampleIndicators` y para que los botones funcionen `data-bs-target` debe apuntar al `id` del carrusel

```
<button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
```

El código completo queda así:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
        
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="4" aria-label="Slide 5"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="5" aria-label="Slide 6"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="../assets/images/carouselPizzeria1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="chef cocinando">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Frescura y calidad</h5>
            <p>En nuestra cocina solo utilizamos productos con estandar de calidad</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../assets/images/carouselPizzeria2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="foto caja de pizza">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Diseño</h5>
            <p>Mantenemos los mas minimos detalles hasta en nuestro packaging</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../assets/images/carouselPizzeria3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="carteleria neon">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Carteleria</h5>
            <p>¡Agregamos nuestro estilo newyorkino a nuestro salon!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../assets/images/carouselPizzeria4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="terraza">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Nuestra gran terraza</h5>
            <p>La terraza mas bella del Village climatizada, con excelente vista</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../assets/images/carouselPizzeria5.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="cocineros pizzeria">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Maestros en lo que hacemos</h5>
            <p>Nuestra cocina goza del personal mas capacitado del mercado</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../assets/images/carouselPizzeria6.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="cocineros pastas">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Al que le quepa el poncho...</h5>
            <p>
              Cada cocinero que trabaja con nosotros, se dedica solo a su especialidad,
              para poder brindar la mejor calidad posible en lo que elabora.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!!! ahi me funciono, claramente estaba el error en el data-bs-target